# How to reflect changes on both One-To-Many-Relationship instances when updating one of them at once in Django?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-admin

I have two tables connected with a **Foreignkey**. I have a field in the main model, its value depends on the child instances.

For example, if I have a Library model and a Book model, Book has Foriegnkey to Library. And we have a field in the Library model which is equal to the "total_price" of all the books in the library. How I can update that field "total_price" whenever I increase the quantity of a certain book or decrease it.

Note that I have to **save each instance separately in order to get the value right**. I have the Books as a TabularInline inside Library, so I make the change to the quantity and save the changes, and then I have to press save one more time to change the "total_price" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I called the save method for the main model after saving the child model.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    library = models.Foreignkey(Library, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    ....
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.price = BookPrice(self)
    super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.library.save()
```